# c# cannot run process(cmd) with custom argument with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

i have a small asp.net web-form application.I am trying to run cmd.exe with given command.I am publishing project to server so i cannot debug it on server.

First , i tried **dir** command it is working as it should be

```
       System.Diagnostics.Process si = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        si.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";
        si.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        si.StartInfo.UserName = "Administrator";
        si.StartInfo.Password = new SecureString();
        si.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c dir";
        si.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        foreach (char c in "pass*")
            si.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar(c);

        si.Start();
        string error = si.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        string output = si.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        si.WaitForExit();
        si.Close();

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error.Trim()))
        {
            throw new Exception("Command cannot be executed");
        }

        //Pre-created .bat file
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\test\s.bat"))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\test\s.bat"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(output);
            }
        }
```

**When i check the .bat file.It is written all directories under c:/ , so it is working

Second , i tried to send my custom command to execute with cmd.exe

the command(argument) that passed is :

```
C:\dev6i\BIN\RWRUN60.EXE userid=user/pass report="h:\avicenna\uyg6i\Mikr2392" BACKGROUND="NO" BATCH="YES" DESFORMAT="pdf" DESNAME="C:\test\reports\report_L_23123_121213.pdf" DESTYPE="FILE"  PARAMFORM="NO" PATID="131233" PRONO="6472886" GROUB="3"
```

it is executing a report program(RWRUN60.exe) with some parameters and this program trigger another(which is on h:/ network folder) to create report pdf on local machine's "C:\test\reports\" folder. When i copied and paste this text to command line(cmd.exe) it is just working without any problem and **pdf is created.**

Here is the code for this:

```
       System.Diagnostics.Process si = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        si.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\test\";
        si.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        si.StartInfo.UserName = "Administrator";
        si.StartInfo.Password = new SecureString();
        si.StartInfo.Arguments = result.command; //result.command is the argument text above
       // si.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c "+result.command; //also tried this , unsure /c is necessary
        si.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        foreach (char c in "pass*")
            si.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar(c);

        si.Start();
        string error = si.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        string output = si.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        si.WaitForExit();
        si.Close();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error.Trim()))
        {
            throw new Exception("Error occured");
        }

        if (File.Exists(@"C:\test\s.bat"))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\test\s.bat"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(output);
            }

        }
```

** with these codes , it just run with any error.But the command is not working  for some reason as **pdf isn't created**. test folder has IIS_USR privileges with full control.I am almost sure it is about the argument but dont know what to do.
What should i check?

Comment: does it work when you run it fully on your machine..? also the application may not have rights to create pdf on everyones local machine.. perhaps you should create a network share and have the files placed in a single location, not multiple spread out locations .. also what if there file path / directory does not exist `if (File.Exists(@"C:\test\s.bat"))`

Comment: Why running `cmd.exe` at all, if your target is already an executable? Just execute `RWRUN60.EXE` and pass it arguments. Also note that executing `RWRUN60.EXE` with working directory set to `C:\test` instead of the directory it is located in (`C:\dev6i\BIN`) may fail in case it depends on some DLLs in that directory.

Comment: Thanks for replies , I have also saved command text to .bat file and run it:  Process.Start(@"C:\test\s.bat") .... it just start and close process but file doesnt created in desired folder. I dont understand that when i click .bat file manually it is just working and file is created but it doesnt work when called like this : Process.Start(@"C:\test\s.bat")